# Как на С++ парсить html страничку?

Tags: html, c++, синтаксический-анализ

Нужно выковыривать текст и удалять все лишнее,  а текст раскидан и разбит по ячейкам таблицы.

Давайте в качестве примера возьмем эту страницу  http://hashcode.ru/questions/120273/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83

не, очень сложная страница. нужно чтото попроще типа хабрахабра

Comment: Хм, может немного не в тему, но не поделитесь ли вашей задачей?

Comment: Точной задачи я не формулировал. Хочу брать страницы и убирать все кроме собственно текста как в аддонах Clearly и Redability, а то надоело, что страницы тянут с собой кучу мусора.

Comment: Интересуют библиотеки парсинга заточенные под html\xml.

Comment: @Alex Dok, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Нет, пока ответа с примером не увидел, а так хотелось)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Либо парсить самому, либо использовать спец. библиотеку например [htmlcxx](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Парсил, используя libxml. Строишь объектную модель, а потом запросами или траверсить дерево. Желательно, но вообще говоря не обязательно, чтобы документ был валиден (по крайней мере корректно сформирован).

Answer (score 1):

Ещё можно использовать flex. Unicode он не понимает, но html-теги как раз можно.

Comment: Почуствовал себя мамонтом: я под `flex` понимаю генератор лексических анализаторов. В принципе в паре с `bison` тоже применимо - построить грамматику и транслятор и погнали :)

Comment: Ну можно обойтись одним лексом, если не нужно проверять правильность вложенности тегов.

Comment: Можно, но это грустные странички какие-то будут только, плоские :)

Comment: Цель то выковырять текст между тегами

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, регулярные выражения для этих целей вполне подойдут. Например, [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html). Алгоритм прост: поиск (`regex_search`) - замена (`regex_replace`), и так до конца файла.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, вы правы, решение не удачное.

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО для просто странички регулярных выражений многовато будет... А в чем проблема то?!

1. Получили страничку
2. Нашли таблицу
3. Разбили содержимое

Что-то конкретное не получается?
Для поиска в тексте можно использовать хоть готовые классы с их функциями типа `find substr` или самому что-нибудь простецкое написать, вроде:

```
static int strfind(const char* src, const char* find, int start = 0)
{
    int len = strlen(src);
    int findlen = strlen(find);
    for (int i = start; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (src[i] == find[0])
        {
            for (int k = i, d = 0; (d <= findlen && k <= len); k++, d++)
            {
                if (d == findlen) return i;
                if (src[k] != find[d]) break;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

//---Эксклюзивная функция абсолютно не похожая ни на что еще
//---Специально для юникода и лично для @Котик_хочет_кушать, )))
static int wcsfind(const wchar_t* src, const wchar_t* find, int start = 0)
{
    int len = wcslen(src);
    int findlen = wcslen(find);
    for (int i = start; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (src[i] == find[0])
        {
            for (int k = i, d = 0; (d <= findlen && k <= len); k++, d++)
            {
                if (d == findlen) return i;
                if (src[k] != find[d]) break;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @lirik90, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: По-сути вы предлагаете реализовать парсинг самому. Зачем изобретать велосипед, если с regex это будет значительно быстрее реализовать и проще поддерживать? Про читабельность кода я вообще не говорю.

Comment: да я догадывался что так бы сделать надо, только никто не предупредил что между текстом и кодом еще и пустую строку оставлять надо(((

Comment: А  что значит проще поддерживать ?=) Если страницу изменят и парсер менять, "реализовать парсер самому", как по мне так это секунд 15 потратить))) в том смысле что быстрее не быстрее это вопрос спорный ИМХО. а код и правда диковатый=)) но работает)

Comment: Давайте вашему коду скормим что-нибудь следующего содержания, а потом вместе посмеемся:

> mor​tal man from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝

Comment: ...Эх, как же я люблю любителей комментировать просто для того что бы комментировать=)