# Парсинг HTML и создание DOM

Tags: html, c++, qt, парсер, dom

Нужно написать простое ядро браузера.
Соответственно нужно как-то парсить HTML и создавать DOM дерево, которое потом будет передаваться в рендер.
Много гуглил, но чего-то конкретного и адекватного не нашёл. Проблема в том, что вся информация либо очень поверхностная, либо находил готовые написанные парсеры, разобраться в которых попросту не смог (+мое знание html очень слабое, а времени на его изучение нет).
Для начала, нужно написать хотя бы парсер (руками с нуля, без использования готовых библиотек для этого). Нагуглил только идеи и примитивные алгоритмы. То есть представляю как это работает, но этого слишком мало для того что бы что-то писать.
Буду очень признателен, если поэтапно расскажите за что браться и что читать (если с примерами хороших статей(очень желательно на русском), то вообще шик)
P.S. В итоге это должно быть написано на Qt, знание которого у меня тоже +- нулевое, но, на сколько я понял, использование его в написании парсера практически не требуется. Однако, если расскажите какие модули будут в этом полезны, буду очень рад

Comment: Простите, но как вы собираетесь писать парсер языка, который не знаете, на фреймворке, который не знаете?

Comment: ну как минимум в вашей программе должен быть лексический анализатор, который будет понимать html и ту нужно еще уточнить html какой версии? ну и как написали выше, без знаний одного и пониманий как работает другое, это не возможно.

Comment: гляньте на этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120273/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: @АлексейУколов, минус на минус дают плюс, значит знание :) А вопрос глуп в данном виде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В простейшем варианте можете использовать `QDomDocument` ([Документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qdomdocument.html)).

Пример:

```
QByteArray data;
...

QDomDocument doc;
if (doc.setContent(data, false, &errorMsg, &errorLine, &errorColumn)) {
  QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
  QDomNode node = root.firstChild();
  while (!node.isNull()) {
    QDomElement el = node.toElement();
    if (!el.isNull()) {
      qDebug() << qPrintable(el.tagName());
    }
    node = node.nextSibling();
  }
}
else {
  qDebug() << QString("Error in line %1, column %2: %3").arg(errorLine).arg(errorColumn).arg(errorMsg);
}
```